# How to set sliding expiration in MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an application built using MVC 5, we have a scenario where users are redirected to the login page when the default session timeout has elapsed even while the user was still typing on a text box. I want users to be redirected to login page only when a page has been left idle for more than 15 minutes but not when users are very. In web forms, we use to set sliding expiration to true in the config file, but that doesn't work in MVC. I will appreciate any assistance.

This is what i have tried:

```
[HttpPost]
 [AllowAnonymous]

public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl, string 
command)
   {
     string decodedUrl = "";
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
      decodedUrl = Server.UrlDecode(returnUrl);
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, false);

     var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.Email,
     DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), false, user.Roles);
     string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
     var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
     encryptedTicket);
     HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
     authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;

      if (Url.IsLocalUrl(decodedUrl))
          {
               return Redirect(decodedUrl);
          }
         else
          {
           return RedirectToAction("analytics", "dashboard");
         }
 }
```

Global ASAX Code:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
    var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                if (authTicket != null && !authTicket.Expired)
                {
                    var roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(',');
                    HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new FormsIdentity(authTicket), roles);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cookie has expired without any requests being made to the server, I don't think there's anything you can do. In your example of the user being kicked out when they are typing in a text box, how does the server know they're doing that?

Assuming there **are** requests hitting the server, in your `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` handler, just check to see if there's an valid existing ticket with less than `X` time remaining on it, and if so, issue a new one by adding it to the response.

Something along these lines:

```
if (authCookie != null)
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    if (authTicket != null && !authTicket.Expired)
    {
        var roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(',');

        var user = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new FormsIdentity(authTicket), roles);

        HttpContext.Current.User = user;

        // Issue new ticket if there is less than 7 minutes remaining on current one.
        if ((authTicket.Expires - DateTime.Now) <= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(7)) 
        {
            var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.Email, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), false, user.Roles);

            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

            var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case, it means session will never expire!

Comment: It will expire after 15 minutes of no requests to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the javascript also.

```
// Set timeout variables.
var timoutWarning = 840000; // Display warning in 14 Mins.
var timoutNow = 900000; // Timeout in 15 mins.
var logoutUrl = '<url>'; // URL to logout page.

var warningTimer;
var timeoutTimer;

// Start timers.
function StartTimers() {
    warningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", timoutWarning);
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);
}

// Reset timers.
function ResetTimers() {
    clearTimeout(warningTimer);
    clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
    StartTimers();
    $("#timeout").dialog('close');
}

// Show idle timeout warning dialog.
function IdleWarning() {
    $("#timeout").dialog({
        modal: true
    });
}

// Logout the user.
function IdleTimeout() {
    window.location = logoutUrl;
}
```

Basically add onload to your body tag calling StartTimers(). You can also add an onmousemove to the body tag which calls ResetTimer() so that as long as there is activity on the page a timeout is not triggered. If no mouse activity is seen on the page the dialog is displayed if movement is detected the dialog is closed and the timers reset.
or you can also handle keypress event to reset timer.

```
<body onload="StartTimers();" onmousemove="ResetTimers();">
```

You can call also MVC Action from the javascript.

Comment: can we prompt and inform user that his or her session is about to expire?

Comment: the function  IdleWarning() will do this. you can write your own dialog opening code here this function will call after 14 min. you can change the value from the variable "timoutWarning"